# Making a Spring Boot Configuration Fault Tolerant

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a Spring Boot Application that relies on various services like Keycloak, Elastic Stack, and PostgreSQL. This application will be deployed to an Kubernetes cluster along with a number of other applications. Is it possible to cause my application to be tolerant of services that may not be available? Imagine if PostgreSQL wasn't up at boot time. Can I force the application to start in a degraded state, notifying the user, log the error, and notifying any calling application of the service degradation? It would also be useful if it could retry auto configuring such beans at an interval.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, everything is possible. Whether that is such a great idea is another matter.

Comment: @JAsgarov If there was a laugh emoticon in this I'd use it. I think the down vote is a bit harsh though.

Comment: @Dave yeah, especially since the Spring team went out of their way to build that functionality lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you asking about @Retryable and @Recover? There's also @Lazy, but the first 2 are probably exactly what you want. That's assuming that your beans don't have retry built in. I.e. the Kafka beans retry automatically. If you are talking rest apis, I'd probably use something like Eureka, Circuit Breaker, etc.

Comment: Fantastic, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question completely. But for the database it's possible to startup spring boot with the database unavailable. If you use [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) then you can configure the connection pool so that it won't try to connect to the database on startup.

```
@Bean
public DataSource xxxDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    config.setUsername("user");
    config.setPassword("password");
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc-url");
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    config.setInitializationFailTimeout(-1);  // <-- This line here is what you need

    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

You won't need to recreate the bean. Every time you try to use the datasource Hikari will try to create a connection. If the database is still down an exception will be thrown. If it's back up then you succeed.

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing this, but I didn't really want to create handlers for every external service. But I suppose, to some degree, it's unavoidable. I think what I'm looking for is exactly what @SledgeHammer suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Your question is vague and too wide in scope. This is not possible if you're using Spring Data, because Spring data will attempt to connect to the DB at startup, and fail if it can't. You can connect yourself, but you'll have to think about connection dropping later, retries, client experience, things like that.

If you want an in-depth analysis, refer to my blog post; it's written for Couchbase database, but addresses the same use case as yours. https://blog.asarkar.com/technical/couchbase-kubernetes/

Comment: I am aware that my question was broad, but that was by design. I wanted to know if there was a framework based solution to what should be a problem common to many external services. I think the answer given by SledgeHammer is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Dave Questions that are vague “by design” end up getting closed by design. So, if you already found a helpful answer, good for you.